# Zabbix active agent - check Internet uptime

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm rolling out Zabbix agents to client servers using Active checks. I'd like to monitor the uptime/downtime of their Internet connection.

My first thought was an item using `net.tcp.service[http, 8.8.8.8]` to contact Google DNS, but it doesn't do what I was expecting.

So my questions are:

1. What's the best way to monitor the Internet connection from an Active agent?
2. Is there a way to test the checks? (I had read about zabbix-get, but believe that's for Passive only)
3. Do Active agents store their data locally if there's no connection, sending it once available? If so, it means I should retrospectively see uptime data if a connection is down. If not, the above is pointless ;-)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You said "it doesn't do what I was expecting" - what were you expecting? Please note that HTTP/TCP is not used for DNS. If you want to check connectivity to Google DNS specifically, try `net.dns[8.8.8.8,google.com]`.

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting to return 1 if it was able to connect, 0 if not. I'll give net.dns a try instead